# Outliers in anova

Tags: anova, outliers

is there some way to identify the outliers numerically from QQ plot?

Many thanks in advance!!!

```
m0 <- aov(y2 ~ bk + bc, data = dat2)
summary(m0)
qqnorm(resid(m0))
qqline(resid(m0))

# with "car" package
library(car)
identify(qqPlot(resid(m0),pch=1))
```